# Can the FirebaseUser become null without invoking AuthStateListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) is `null` if there is no signed in user, non null if there exists a user signed in to `Firebase` from that instance of the app. [`AuthStateListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener.html#onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)) is invoked, if registered properly, when the auth status changes, ie a user signs in or signs out.

I want to know if there is any way possible for the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser` to start returning null suddenly (given that it had been returning non null `FirbaseUser` up to that point) while the app is running without invoking the aforementioned listener.

If it is not possible, then I can safely use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser` without having to worry about `NPE`.

Nowhere in the `Firebase` docs this behaviour is guaranteed that the `AuthStateListener` is invoked if and only if the value returned by `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malcolm from the Firebase Auth team here. As [the documentation states](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener), the AuthStateListener will be triggered:

- Right after the listener has been registered
- When a user is signed in
- When the current user is signed out
- When the current user changes

That is an implicit promise that if the user state changes (and a sign-out is a user state change), the AuthStateListener will be triggered.

Hope that helps!